# Why doesnt byebug/pry stop at the breakpoint in Rspec ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actionmailer, pry, byebug

I try to debug my user_mailer.rb within my test environment. But I dont know why the debugger doesnst stop where it suppose to.

So, the code I roughly have is:
`user_mailer_spec.rb`

```
describe UserMailer do
  describe '#send_notification_letters' do
    # bunch of code omitted here ...
    it 'should record itself to the database'
      expect { UserMailer.send_notification_letters(user) }.to change{SentMail.count}.by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

In `user_mailer.rb`

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def send_notification_letters(user)
    byebug # should break here but doesnt, 
           # also tried binding.pry here, also doesnt work
    # buggy code ...
    # buggy code ...
    # buggy code ...

    SentMail.create(...) # never reached
    mail(to:..., from:...)
  end
end
```

The question is, why is byebug/pry not stopping in the `user_mail.rb` when i run the test `rspec spec/mailer/user_mailer_spec.rb`?

And why?

How to make it stop at that break point?

Is there a bug in the debugger?

Comment: What do you get in the logs?

Comment: This happens to me frequently unless I also add `require 'byebug'` above the `byebug` line.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady, there are only bunch of SQL transaction logs in test.log, which means UserMailer. send_notification_letters() is executed. But the debugger is not stopped. Nothing in the logs about the debugger.

Comment: @infused, tried `require 'byebug'`, did nothing for me

Comment: does adding the byebug before the expect work ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady yes, byebug works within the `it` block

Comment: are you using any delayed jobs, sidekiq, resque etc.. ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I'm using delayed_job, but I thought by calling UserMailer.send_notification_letters(), i would just build the mail object, and nothing to do with delayed_job's queing. Rails magic might prove me wrong

Answer (score 2):

`UserMailer.send_notification_letters(user)` does not actually call the the `send_notification` action, but instead it returns an `ActionMailer::MessageDelivery` object. You need to invoke the delivery in order to hit the method, like this:

`UserMailer.send_notification_letters(user).deliver_now`

You can read more on the topic in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer::Base-label-Sending+mail

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same situation today. After digging around, I've found my issue is caused by the `thin` server's `daemonize` configuration.

Edit your `config/thin.yml`:

```
daemonize: false
```

Or you can just comment out the `thin` gem in your Gemfile, use the default `WEBrick` instead.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I believe its not a `thin` problem in general cuz I'm not using it. :)

Comment: Same here. I'm using Puma.

Comment: I would upvote this a thousand times if I could; has been driving me nuts, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just restart the server.

In my case puma, and without spring.